# How to find the right scaling for exponential distribution

Tags: distributions, density-function, exponential-distribution, complex-numbers

I have a complex Gaussian variable, $Z=X+jY$ with $X,Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$, and I would like to find the parameter that scales the distribution of the squared magnitude $P=|Z|^2$. As expected the resulting distribution of $P$ has shape as Exponential(1/2), however, depending on  $\sigma^2$ the values of $P$ could become completely different as compared to Exponential(1/2); Even though the shape of their PDFs is the same the scaling on the x axis is different.

How can I scale down $P$ in order to get it matching with the exponential distribution?

Comment: Divide all values of $|Z|^2$ by $\sigma^2.$  But that's so simple and obvious it makes me believe I have misread your question.  Is it possible $\sigma$ is unknown and  you need to estimate it from data?

Comment: Hi @whuber, thanks for your answer. I was dividing by the variance but still had difference between the two. However, I've just solved my problem - It turns out that the parameter for the exponential distribution must be 1 and not 0.5.